# Using an image as a mask for another image

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, filter, mask

I've asked this question already, but I've given it a go since. Here's my 
code, with a doc string to show what I'm trying to do.

```
"""
w1_w2_filter_mask2.py
Use xbulge-mask.fits image file as a mask for W1 and W2 bands
and compute the median in patches where the image is not masked
"""
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from astropy.io import fits
from scipy.ndimage.filters import generic_filter as gf

#   Open data files
hdulist = fits.open('xbulge-w1.fits')
w1data = hdulist[0].data
hdulist2 = fits.open('xbulge-w2.fits')
w2data = hdulist2[0].data

hdulistmask = fits.open('xbulge-mask.fits')
maskdata = hdulistmask[0].data

#   Define physical shape of filter patch
def patch_filter(image_data, radius):
    kernel = np.zeros((2*radius+1, 2*radius+1))
    y, x = np.ogrid[-radius:radius+1, -radius:radius+1]
    patch = x**2 + y**2 <= radius**2
    kernel[patch] = 1                
    filtered_image = gf(image_data, np.median, footprint = kernel)
    return filtered_image

#   Apply mask to image files
mx1 = np.ma.masked_array(w1data, mask=maskdata)
mx2 = np.ma.masked_array(w2data, mask=maskdata)

#   Pass median filtering patch across masked image
radius = 25
w1masked_filtered = patch_filter(mx1, radius)
w2masked_filtered = patch_filter(mx2, radius)
```

When I print or imshow the masked, filtered array, it has the same effect as when I don't apply the mask image, i.e. (load mask -> load image -> apply mask -> filter in patches) has the same effect as (load image -> filter in patches).

Can anyone see what I'm missing?